How to upload jar file to the remote repository with all dependencies using Gradle
I have a gradle project with a publishing block. I want to publish my library to the maven private repository without proxy to a central repository. I need to copy all of the project dependencies into the distance repository also. Is it possible to be done with the gradle and its plugins?
